# Handling bad g-code in typical CNC machines based on G02 example

Tags: cnc

I take the following example g-code
https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/g-code-explained-list-of-most-important-g-code-commands/

```
G00 X5 Y5
G01 X0 Y20 F200
G01 X20 Y0
G02 X10 Y-10 I0 J-10        <------------ this and
G02 X-4 Y-8 I-10 J0         <------------ this part are interesting 
G01 X-26 Y-2
```

Both of the G02 commands instruct to move along a circular arc and set the center point of this arc using I and J coordinates. In the example above these center points together with the X,Y coordinates indeed define circles. What does typical machine do if the center point is invalid? i.e. if I set G02 X10 Y-10 I1 J-13. Will it typically throw an error or try to cut in a weird manner?

Comment: Have you seen the videos of cnc machines crashing into the head? Perhaps these are not codes written to be used but to show code only.

Comment: I've seen this and that's clear to me. The question is more about the logic of the machine, when the initial point and the new point have different distance to the specified center point. If this is a an error state for the machine or is it indeed a Circular INTERPOLATION and the machine typically chooses the radius based e.g. on the position only of the first point but stops in the point closest to the second one.

Comment: depends how the machine should be programmed ie always from 0,0,0 or each action end point is now 0,0,0...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.